# Setting Up React-Redux with Draft-JS Props Issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, draftjs

I'm new to working with React and I'm trying to integrate DraftJS with React and Redux. I'm getting an error message about passing in props, and I'm not sure why the props are not being passed. So I guess the bigger question is how do I get DraftJS to work React and Redux and the more immediate question is this error message.

Here are the [DraftJS docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/quickstart-api-basics.html#content)

This is the error message I am getting

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
in Route (created by AppRouter)
in AppRouter
in Provider
```

Here is the AppRouter File

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import PostsIndex from '../components/posts/PostsIndex';
import PostNew from '../components/posts/PostNew';
import PostEdit from '../components/posts/PostEdit';
import PostShow from '../components/posts/PostShow';

export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostNew} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id/edit" component={PostEdit} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostShow} exact={true} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Here is the Posts Reducer File

```
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';

const defaultState = {
  editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
};

const postsReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
console.log('redux action: ', action.payload);
switch(action.type){
case 'START_ADD_POST':
  return {
    ...state,
    action
  }
  default: 
    return state
  }
};

export default postsReducer;
```

The console.log in the postsReducer is showing me this

```
PostNew {props: undefined, context: undefined, refs: {…}, updater: {…}}
```

Here is the Posts Action File

```
export const startAddPost = (editorState) => ({
 type: 'START_ADD_POST',
 editorState
});
```

Here is the Store File

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import postsReducer from '../reducers/posts';

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      posts: postsReducer
    })
  ); 
  return store;
};
```

Here is the NewPost Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { startAddPost } from '../../actions/posts';
import PostForm from './PostForm';

export class PostNew extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>New Post</h1>
        <PostForm />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state", state);
  return {
    post: state
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startAddPost: (editorState) => dispatch(startAddPost(post))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostNew);

console.log('PostNew', new PostNew());
```

Here is what the console.log on PostNew returns

```
state 
{posts: {…}}
posts
:
editorState
:
EditorState
_immutable
:
Record {_map: Map}
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
```

Here is the PostForm Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

export default class PostForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.state.onChange} />
    )
  }
}
```